# Order of Elements in Quotient Groups (Proof)

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group and N $\lhd$ of G such that [G : N] = 100. Suppose that a $\in$ G such that $a^{23}$ = e, where e is the identity element of G. Show that a $\in$ N.

Since the order of the group G/N is 100 then $(aN)^{100}$ = N since $a^{100}N$ = $N$ which implies that $a^{100}N \in N$

Since $a^{23}$ = e and $a^{23} \subseteq a^{100}$, ($\Rightarrow$) $a^{23}N = N$ ($\Rightarrow$) $eN = N$. Thus, $a \in N$

Does this proof make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: You're on the right track to observe that $a^{100} \in N$, but your assertion that $a^{23} \subset a^{100}$ is nonsensical. What do you mean here? Do you mean $a^{23} \in \langle a^{100} \rangle$? Even then, that still doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I was trying to figure out the significance of $a^{23}$ in $a^{100}$ beyond the fact that it's the identity element.

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with the argument. You can't say $a^{100}N \in N$ since $a^{100}N$ is a set but you can say $a^{100} \in N$, which is the correct implication of $a^{100}N = N$. It does not make sense to say $a^{23} \subseteq a^{100}$ since $a^{23}$ and $a^{100}$ are elements of $G$, not sets.

Since you know that $a^{23} = e$, you have $(aN)^{23} = a^{23}N = eN = N$. Thus, the order of $aN$ divides $23$. Since $G/N$ has order $100$, the order of $aN$ also divides $100$. Thus $|aN|$ divides $gcd(23, 100)$, which equals $1$. Thus, $aN = N$, which shows that $a \in N$.

Comment: Thank you, is this result is only relevant if a is raised to a prime number?

Comment: The result is true as long as $a^n = e$ for $n$ relatively prime to $100$. So even $n = 99$ will do.

Comment: More generally, if $\text{gcd}(r,n) = 1$, $[G:N] = r$, and $a^n = e$, then $a \in N$.

Answer (score 1):

The expresion $a^{23}\subseteq a^{100}$ has no sense, and in the implications you are only multiplying by $e$.

Observe that, since $a^{23}=e$ and $23$ is a prime, we must have $ord(a)\in \{1,23\}$. If $ord(a)=1$, we have $a=e\in N$. If $ord(a)=23$, we have $ord(aN)\in \{1,23\}$ in $G/N$. Since that $23$ is not a divisor of $100$, we have $aN=N$